# Why Yii2 ActiveRecord joinWith making 2 selects

Tags: mysql, activerecord, yii2

guys. Have some code:

```
City::find()->joinWith('country')->all();
```

City model:

```
class City extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public function getCountry()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Country::className(), ['id' => 'countryId']);
    }
}
```

[image: screenshot]

But in debugger i can see 2 queries. What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: where you are using/invoking  this code ..  in a controller/action ?   ... show the related  code please ..

Comment: just in action. actionTest() { City::find()->joinWith('country')->all(); return ''; } @scaisEdge

Comment: no view ?  ..no render ?  no nothing other? only this code  ?

Comment: yes, only this code, nothing more. @scaisEdge

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#lazy-eager-loading

Answer (score 0):

Try this for single time execute the query.

```
//second parameter in joinWith will stop to load lazy loading 
City::find()->joinWith('country', false)->all();
```